# How can i know SHA-1 key of testkey in zipsigner app?

Tags: android, sha1

I have the source code of zip-signer application. I want to know the SHA-1 key of zip-signer application, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but the SHA1 fingerprint of a built-in key can be obtained as follows...

```
import kellinwood.security.zipsigner.ZipSigner;
import kellinwood.security.zipsigner.optional.Fingerprint;

ZipSigner zipsigner = new ZipSigner();

// Load the key/cert pair for the built-in key "testkey"
zipsigner.loadKeys("testkey")

// Get the SHA1 fingerprint of the cert
String testkeySHA1Fingerprint = Fingerprint.hexFingerprint("SHA1", zipsigner.getKeySet().getPublicKey().getEncoded())
```

The certificate of the ZipSigner application itself is not part of the source code.